# UTF-8 encoding for non-character keys

Tags: python, utf-8, keyboard, hid

I think I may know the answer to this just given that I haven't been able to find anything on it but is there a UTF-8 encoding for non-character keys like `Shift`, `Control`, `Alt`, etc?

Context: I have an RPi acting as an HID device that is "writing" to the target pc under `/dev/hidg0` in the following python function:

```
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())
```

is there an alternative to the `.write()` method or more preferably is there a UTF-8 encoding for non-character keys?

Comment: Keyboards generally don't do character encodings, just scan codes. Maybe this will help: [Using RPi Zero as a Keyboard Part 3: Sending and receiving reports](https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/using-rpi-zero-as-keyboard-send-reports)